# Create or replace and resolve Java source, I am not able to create a function using java source

Tags: java, oracle

Oracle environment.

The following Java source has been correctly compiled:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE AND RESOLVE JAVA SOURCE NAMED hr.roman
   AS package Package.NumeriRomani;

class Numero{
    String r="";
    int a=0;

    Numero(int n){
        a=n;
            if(n==0){
                r="NULL";
                return;}
            while(n>=1000){
                    r+="M";
                    n-=1000;}
            if(n>=900){
                    r+="CM";
                    n-=900;}
            while(n>=500){
                    r+="D";
                    n-=500;}
            if(n>=400){
                    r+="CD";
                    n-=400;}
            while(n>=100){
                    r+="C";
                    n-=100;}
            if(n>=90){
                    r+="XC";
                    n-=90;}
            while(n>=50){
                    r+="L";
                    n-=50;}
            if(n>=40){
                    r+="XL";
                    n-=40;}
            while(n>=10){
                    r+="X";
                    n-=10;}
            if(n>=9){
                    r+="IX";
                    n-=9;}
            if(n>=5){
                    r+="V";
                    n-=5;}
            if(n==4){
                    r+="IV";
                    n-=4;}
            while(n>=1){
                    r+="I";
                    n--;}
    }//Numero(int)
    Numero(String k){
        int vCor,vNext;
        r=k;
        for(int i=0;;i++){
            vCor=valore(k.charAt(i));
            if(i==k.length()-1){
                a+=vCor;
                break;}
            vNext=valore(k.charAt(i+1));
            if(vCor>=vNext)
                a+=vCor;
            else
                a-=vCor;
        }
    }

    static public int valore(char c){
        switch(c){
          case 'I': return 1;
            case 'V': return 5;
            case 'X': return 10;
            case 'L': return 50;
            case 'C': return 100;
            case 'D': return 500;
            case 'M': return 1000;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }

    public int getArabo(){
        return a;
    }
    public String getRomano(){
        return r;
    }
    }
/
```

I would like to create a function for getArabo and a function for getRoman, but I always receive errors.

I have tried with:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION hr.converti (alfa IN varchar2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
AS
   LANGUAGE JAVA
   NAME 'ROMAN.getArabo(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

but I receive the error:

```
select hr.converti('XII') from dual;
```

ORA-29540: ROMAN class does not exist

How could I fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are the things you need to correct to be able to use this java class:

1. Use static methods so that they can be called from Oracle without object instantiation
2. Your source is named `ROMAN`, but your class is named `Numero`. You will reference the class when calling it from Oracle. **Giving both the class and the source the same name will prevent confusion.**
3. java is strongly typed, you can't convert the method `int getArabo()` to:

   ```
   getArabo(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String
   ```

Here's a working example:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "Roman" AS
  2  class Roman {
  3     public static int getArabo(java.lang.String x){
  4          return 0;
  5      }
  6  }
  7  /

Java created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION converti (alfa IN varchar2)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'Roman.getArabo(java.lang.String) return int';
  4  /

Function created

SQL> select converti ('aaa') from dual;

CONVERTI('AAA')
---------------
              0
```

---

Additionally, you can use Oracle functions to convert a number to its character value in roman with [`TO_CHAR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#i34570) (but the `TO_NUMBER` function can't be used for the reverse operation):

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(2013, 'RN') FROM dual;

TO_CHAR(2013,'RN')
------------------
         MMXIII
```

Comment: What is the opposite command of to_char(2013, 'RN')? How can I come back to arabic numbers, starting from MMXIII?  SELECT TO_NUMBER ('MMXIII', 'NR') from DUAL does not work.

Comment: I am encountering problems correcting my source, could you help me please?

Comment: If this is related to the mapping between Oracle and java, you should edit your question. If this is related to your java conversion function, it might be a better idea to post a specific question.